# Polygon Pre-Processing [Sub Division and Triangulation] is not performant with polygons having coordinates > 200k

Tags: geospatial, data-preprocessing, jts

I have some polygons that are quite big like having coordinates greater than 200k for those I have subdivided them into smaller pieces like this. ([it was suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64258720/439194))

But still, some of the subdivided polygons have coordinates greater than 10k so for that I have used the triangulation like this.

```
DelaunayTriangulationBuilder delaunayTriangulationBuilder =
            new DelaunayTriangulationBuilder();
delaunayTriangulationBuilder.setSites(dividedPieceOfGeometry);
Geometry triangles = delaunayTriangulationBuilder.getTriangles(geometryFactory);
IntStream.range(0, triangles.getNumGeometries())
        .parallel()
        .mapToObj(triangles::getGeometryN)
        .map(geometryN -> geometryN.intersection(dividedPieceOfGeometry))
        .flatMap(
            possibleGeometryCollection -> {
              List<Geometry> collectedGeometries = new ArrayList<>();
              filterFromPossibleGeometries(possibleGeometryCollection, collectedGeometries); //this just extracts the geometries out of GeometryCollection
              return collectedGeometries.stream();
            })
        .toList()
```

Now this whole process is quite time-consuming, and I wanted to improve the performance of this pre-processing.

I am using the JTS Topology Suite to implement this functionality.

Sample Polygon: This particular polygon has 6 million points in it.

[image: Sample Polygon]

Comment: Do you really need that many points? Could you simplify the polygons before triangulation?

Comment: Yes I do need all the points as if I simplify the original polygon it slightly changes the shape and which is not acceptable for my use case to detect whether ship is in the polygon or not.

Comment: I doubt that, how accurate is the ship's position compared to the accuracy of the polygon? For best speed chop the polygon in to very small boxes and add an index

Comment: I want accuracy up to meters from the edge of the polygon, 
and if I simplify the polygon, I might trigger inaccurate events for the ship entry and exit from the polygon or zone like late detection or early exit.

Also, I have started to subdivide the polygons as you suggested after subdividing I have some boxes that still have lots of points so for those particular polygons I am using triangulation to have a faster search operation.

Comment: Do you know how big a ship is? I would just use smaller boxes in those rather than triangles, but since this is a preprocessing step does speed really matter

Comment: Mostly ships will be tug, cargo, utility and fishing ships and yes I have started to subdivide the polygons into smaller pieces now but still some polygons have huge points but as you said it's a preprocessing I need to think of preprocessing all the polygon before feeding it to actual service.